# Images won't stay in Div

Tags: html, css

I am having issues with div's overflowing their content when the browser is resized. I've read multiple solutions on this site that specifies the correct use of overflow: hidden and position: relative, however when I attempt to implement those solutions it just breaks other things. I think I'm missing some insider trick around how to correctly wrap and apply these settings. E.g applying overflow: hidden to the wrapper fixes the cog icons overflowing but breaks the left menu's dropdown in the process.

Both of these menu's will have dropdowns. I'm probably taking an incorrect approach to this or the recommended solutions on this site would undoubtedly work. Just looking for a pointer on this one.

It's just 2 x menus inside of a wrapper (right menu cog icons are placeholders and will become drop down menu's also).

[image]
*When full size the Navbar acts as expected*

[image]
*When resizing the page in my browser you can see the icons overflowing*

```css
#menu, #menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
#menuwrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 37.6px;
    background-color: #111;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #777;
}
#menu {
    width: 980px; /*width of menu*/
    margin: 0px auto; /*margin from top of page*/
    float: left;
}
#menu:before,
 #menu:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

#menu:after {
    clear: both;
}

#menu {
    zoom: 1;
}
#menu li {
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #222;
    box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #444;
    position: relative;
}

#menu a {
    float: left;
    padding: 12px 30px;
    color: #999;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font: bold 12px Arial, Helvetica;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
       
}

#menu li:hover > a {
    color: #fafafa;
}

*html #menu li a:hover { /* IE6 only */
    color: #fafafa;
}
#menu ul {
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    _margin: 0; /*IE6 only*/
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 38px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #444;
    background: linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

#menu li:hover > ul {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    margin: 0;
}

#menu ul ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 150px;
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    _margin: 0; /*IE6 only*/
    box-shadow: -1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3);
}

#menu ul li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    border: 0;
    _line-height: 0; /*IE6 only*/
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111, 0 2px 0 #666;
}

#menu ul li:last-child {
    box-shadow: none;
}

#menu ul a {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 130px;
    _height: 10px; /*IE6 only*/
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: none;
    text-transform: none;
}

#menu ul a:hover {
    background-color: #0186ba;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#04acec, #0186ba);
}
#menu ul li:first-child > a {
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}

#menu ul li:first-child > a:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    top: -6px;
    border-left: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: 6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #444;
}

#menu ul ul li:first-child a:after {
    left: -6px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    border-left: 0;
    border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
    border-top: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: 6px solid #3b3b3b;
}

#menu ul li:first-child a:hover:after {
    border-bottom-color: #04acec;
}

#menu ul ul li:first-child a:hover:after {
    border-right-color: #0299d3;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

#menu ul li:last-child > a {
    border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
}
#usermenu {
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
    height: inherit;
    border-radius: 0px; /*Round the edges*/
    overflow:hidden;
}
#usermenu img {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="navbar.css">
    
</head>

<div id="menuwrapper">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Categories</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Stuff</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="usermenu">
        <a href="#"><img  src="images/SettingsCog_24x24.png" alt="User Settings" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/SettingsCog_24x24.png" alt="User Settings" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/SettingsCog_24x24.png" alt="User Settings" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/SettingsCog_24x24.png" alt="User Settings" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/SettingsCog_24x24.png" alt="User Settings" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What behavior do you want when the window is resized? Do you just simply want to hide the overflown content?

Comment: is the problem happening when the window is at 767px? Check with developer tools of your browser. Where is the breaking Point?

Comment: @Aziz pretty much. I just want them to stay in the Div and be covered like there position is static. In other words when I resize and the icons are outside of the window I should not see them because they are off to the right.

Comment: @hansTheFranz I can't really tell the exact point but I would assume it happens when the browser window goes below the 980px specified for the left menu. When I resize the cogs move left and then drop to the next line. I simply want the right menu div 'usermenu' to stay in place and get cut off by the browser upon resize as opposed to it contracting and then dropping to the next line.